# Sistema de atualização do kernel no Android

Tags: android, kernel

Navegando pelo site https://android.googlesource.com/ percebi que tem muitas pessoas fazendo alterações no código fonte do sistema Android. Inclusive sei que patches de correção de bugs e vulnerabilidades são "commitados" lá.

Eu estou tentando fazer um aplicativo que diagnostica um dispositivo quanto as suas vulnerabilidades com base em metadados do dispositivo como, versao do android, versão do kernel, build number, build timestamp, etc.

Existe uma vulnerabilidade que afeta várias versões do android, inclusive a do meu dispositivo (Jelly Bean 4.1.2), mas segundo o aplicativo "Trustable", meu dispositivo está protegido contra esta vulnerabilidade. O patch de correção desta vulnerabilidade foi lançado/commitado em 2013, e o build timestamp (data de compilação do sistema) do meu dispositivo é de 2014. Talvez por isso meu dispositivo não seja suscetível a tal vulnerabilidade. Mas isto é só uma especulação, e eu queria de ter certeza.

Gostaria de saber como ocorrem as atualizações do sistema; se ocorrem, por exemplo, em um determinado intervalo de tempo, se estas atualizações modificam o build timestamp do sistema, e principalmente, se eu posso garantir que meu dispositivo não é suscetível a uma determinada vulnerabilidade caso o build timestamp, ou seja, a data de compilação do meu sistema (kernel) seja superior à data de lançamento da correção da vulnerabilidade.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Se alguém puder citar uma fonte para que eu possa obter tais informações eu agradeceria bastante.